# Invalid Key Hash, The Key Hash does not match - Android FB login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash, key

I try to generate a key hash for my production android app, I use the steps provided by the Facebook Developer documentation.

snipet from FB docs:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias fbreleasekey -keystore /Mobile\ Development/gastro_key | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I use the same keystore file which I have used to sign my app, it asks for a password while generating, and outputs a key hash. But When I add this to my FB dev. settings I get the same error telling me that they do not match when launching the app.

I was reading that I could simply copy and paste the key hash form the error message, but I don't think if this would last.

What could be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Check the alias, password or path of the key. If any of them are wrong it will generate a different keyhash

Comment: @akash93 - THANKS! You see, this answer is nowhere to find here on stack overflow. My alias was wrong. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keytool will generate a keyhash even if you supply wrong arguments.
Check the alias, password or path of the key. If any of them are wrong it will generate a different keyhash.