# facebook login with sdk

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I trying to open a Session with the latest facebook sdk and I am getting this exception :

```
com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash roW2JuBZHMEss1AFEoFPW-ngTcY does not match any stored key hashes.
```

I calculated my real hash which is :

roW2JuBZHMEss1AFEoFPW+ngTcY=

```
calculated   : roW2JuBZHMEss1AFEoFPW+ngTcY=
shown in log : roW2JuBZHMEss1AFEoFPW-ngTcY
```

There are pretty close but not the same, I try to put the hash shown in log in my FB settings  but FB isn't accepting it because of its not valid length.

When I try to display the key at run time it also show the key roW2JuBZHMEss1AFEoFPW+ngTcY=

Any ideas of what is wrong  ?

thanks

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485004/android-app-key-hash-doesnt-match-any-stored-key-hashes/19499368#19499368

Comment: yes know I that it is a facebook bug... I will need to see how I can generate a new debug.keystore and make sure that its hash doesn't containt any special char....

Comment: awfully I am not abale to generate a key which is not ending by "=".
so I am stuck. I filled a facebook bug...

Comment: Did u create an app ID from facebook developers website ???

Comment: yes I did but I am not sure I am using it in my code :S