# Facebook SDK - Keyhashs does not match

Tags: android, facebook

I use this code to generate my app keyhash:

```
public static String getKeyHash(Context context) {
    String returner = "";
    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.abc.mypackage", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            returner = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e(TAG, Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());

    }
    return returner;
}
```

The function is called from `onCreate` function of Main Activity. And the generated hash is

`ki4PhEa/cy/qsP/omrTEPkYFCDE=`

Due to this [Android app Key Hash doesn't match any stored key hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485004/android-app-key-hash-doesnt-match-any-stored-key-hashes), I replaced all the `/` to `_` and finally I get this

`ki4PhEa_cy_qsP_omrTEPkYFCDE=`

I put the keyhash to the Facebook developer site and save

[image]

When I login to Facebook, my app gives this exception (awesome !!!!)

```
02-26 23:05:49.008    4966-4966/? E/MyClassListViewAdapter﹕ Bad thing happened com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: UnknownError: ApiException:Key hash ki4PhEa_cy_qsP_omrTEPkYFCDE does not match any stored key hashes.
```

How can I solve this ridiculous problem ?

**Update** This problem only occurs on my real device (Htc One X). It does not occur when running on emulator

Answer (score 0):

You need to use keytool to generate your key hash from the certificates that are used when you sign your app.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> 
| openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

You can do it for both your debug and release keystores.

Comment: I used `keytool` at the first time, and got that exception so I switched to use the hash calculating function. By the way, I just run the keytool again and it gives the result `bLxqLn/RXHcNbPbGMPFfbQPDlY8=`. I replaced `/` to `_` again and put to facebook developer site. Again, still does not work on my real device. Please have a look at my updated question

Answer (score 0):

I seriously have no idea but it started to work after I add the key with the `/` (instead of removing it)

`ki4PhEa/cy/qsP/omrTEPkYFCDE=`

[image]