# Login error in "Invalid key hash"

Tags: android, facebook

i have implement facbook in my application and submitted my key hashes but it display an error at release key time "Invalid key hash.The key hash XXXXXX does not match any stored key hashes. Configure you...." it's working fine when i use debug key.
please help me.

i am using this approach for release key-

keytool -exportcert -alias 

  -keystore 
  
    | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

```
and for debug key useing this approch

try {
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
"com.samsung.smart_learning",
PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
md.reset();
md.update(signature.toByteArray());
Log.d("KeyHash:++++++++++++++++++++",
Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
System.out.println("shivansj_++"+ Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Comment: copy that key and place = at the end, paste it in your facebook setting screen and check again, it will work

Comment: i have try it but still i am getting same error..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485004/android-app-key-hash-doesnt-match-any-stored-key-hashes this might help you

Comment: thanks ravi for reply but i have use these thing also.