# Flutter Login with Facebook issues

Tags: flutter, facebook-login, flutter-dependencies

I am new to Flutter World.
I am trying to use Login with Facebook. But the issue i am facing is that if my phone doesn't have Facebook Application, the Login with Facebook works fine as it ask for the facebook username and password.

But if my phone has my facebook application, it throws the below error. Please see the below error :
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kjoo.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this may help you [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485004/android-app-key-hash-doesnt-match-any-stored-key-hashes)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick Google search perhaps this could help:

if you have facebook installed on your device then it will produce this error but if you uninstall the facebook app then it will work correctly
Or maybe whichever Key is coming in your error page. Add the same key in your Developer account

Make sure you check this out also:

[Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)

Comment: I have facebook installed on my device and it gives me the error as shown in the screenshot when i am using Login with Facebook in my Flutter app. I basically wants the Login with Facebook feature to work in my Flutter app even if i have Facebook app  installed on my phone.

Comment: I found a similar thread which may help https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301025/facebook-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes&ved=2ahUKEwjj5LyiivbfAhUJzlkKHfIpDuMQjjgwAHoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3FuRL4a_zrfJIDBZbqS16j